# Can i add money to a google play gift card and how

Tags: google-play-store

Can I add funds, and how if I can. If I had a 10 pound Google play card and I needed 14 pounds on it can i add 4 pounds to it?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is to your question is No, you cannot add an amount to a gift card after purchase. You'll have to purchase another gift card & redeem both in order to accumulate the desired amount.

**As per the Comments**

There is no information which actually states this. but [this document](https://play.google.com/intl/ALL_ALL/about/card-terms/) says that user can use multiple gift cards to complete the purchase. What I've seen is, third party seller sells the gift card & updates the gift card number with the amount to google. so I don't think there is any provision to update amount later. otherwise they would have stated that way.
 https://play.google.com/intl/ALL_ALL/about/card-terms/

Comment: Any supportive information to link to? Some rule or policy stated somewhere accessible to document this?

Comment: there is no information which actually states this. but in below-given documents says that user can use multiple gift cards to complete the purchase. What I've seen is, third party seller sells the gift card & updates the gift card number with the amount to google. so I don't think there is any provision to update amount later. otherwise they would have stated that way. https://play.google.com/intl/ALL_ALL/about/card-terms/

Comment: People tend not to read comments, and, they are transitory, so information can be lost. Please edit your additional information into your post to solidify it. Thanks.

Comment: Done that . Thanks